# Writing an updating value to the console with Symfony

Tags: unix, symfony

Utilities like `wget` can write their download percentage to the console and keep updating it without writing a new line. What's this feature called and is it possible with Symfony's console component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used 1ed's answer to see how Symfony does it with the progress helper, available in 2.2. The hex character code "\x08" (ANSI backspace character) will delete single character. If you track the length of the last line, and use str_repeat, this achieves the desired effect.

Proof of concept:

```
<?php
$lastLineSize = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i <= 50; $i++) {
    echo str_repeat("\x08", $lastLineSize);
    echo "Iteration {$i} of 50";
    $lastLineSize = strlen("Iteration {$i} of 50");
    usleep(100000);
}

echo " - Done\n";
```

Output:

```
[root@dev /home/myuser] > php test.php
Iteration 50 of 50 - Done
[root@dev /home/myuser] >
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on the master branch you can use the [progress helper](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressHelper.php) ([docs](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/console/introduction.html#displaying-a-progress-bar)).